# Local Notification with Adobe AIR on Android

Tags: air, notifications, adobe, local

Is there a way to send local notifications with Adobe AIR on Android? I mean really *local* notifications, I don't want to use a server for this, so when my application runs in the background, it should be able to fire a notification. I also need a way to update the status bar. Is there a Native Extension for that?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This ANE is what I was looking for.
http://www.nativext.com/ane-by-os/ios/notification-native-extension-for-air/

Answer (score 0):

Yes.

You might find a free option on here:

http://sleepydesign.blogspot.co.uk/2012/07/ane-free-air-native-extensions.html

Failing that Distriqt ANE's definitely work.

http://distriqt.com/native-extensions